# How to fix "Property __ does not exist on type 'unknown' "

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to map data coming in from my Cloud Firestore collection and tried to call a specific type of key coming in. Instead it spat out `Property 'desc' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)` in my IDE. Any reason why this is occurring?

```js
descArray;
idArray;
buses = [];

...

.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.descArray = res.map(thisbus => thisbus.payload.doc.data().desc);
      console.log(this.descArray);
      this.idArray = res.map(thisbus => thisbus.payload.doc.data().UID);
      console.log(this.idArray);

      for(let i in this.descArray) {
        console.log(this.descArray[i])
        console.log(this.idArray[i])

        this.buses.push({
          id: this.idArray[i],
          desc: this.descArray[i]
        })
      }
```

**EDIT:** I put in a debugger line and did `console.log(thisbus.payload.doc.data())` and returned this:

```
{UID: "001", desc: "Bus 33", lat: 47.522775, long: -121.82}
UID: "001"
desc: "Bus 33"
lat: 47.522775
long: -121.82
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ ()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: I think it should be `thisbus.payload.doc.data().desc()`

Comment: No joy. It's not a function, and should be `thisbus.payload.doc.data().desc`, not `.desc` being a function.

Comment: can you console.log thisbus.payload.doc.data() and provide the result here

Comment: Alright, I edited the question with the result.

Comment: what is the infered type of `res` and `res.map(thisbus => thisbus.payload.doc.data())`?

Comment: could you show the whole function, both from service and component.